# INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm building a **react-native** mobile application for my university IOT project. After complete the UI part I connected the firebase to my app. Then, I add the **firestore** configuration. After that this error happened. What can I do?

*Here is my app.json file.*

```
{
  "name": "monkey-repellent-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^4.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "expo": "~50.0.4",
    "expo-image": "~1.10.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "firebase": "^10.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

- Actually I tried many things. I deleted node modules and installed them again. But it didn't work.
- Firstly, I used `react-native-firebase` and `react-native-firestore` dependencies. Then I changed them to `@expo-firebase` dependencies. But it also did't work.